# Rust convert a Vec<&str> to a single &str

Tags: rust, unsafe

edit: I'm really dumb, I forgot that vectors need constant sized elements :)

I want to convert a `Vec<&str>` to a single `&str`.

As an example I want `{"a","bc"} -> "abc"`

I know you can use the `join("")` method to accomplish this, but because the memory is already laid out correctly this feels redundant. I wanted to do this a different way.

I wrote a function to do this, but it uses `unsafe`. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

```rust
fn vec_to_str(input: Vec<&str>) -> Option<&str> {
    let last_elem = input.last()?;
    unsafe {
        let last = last_elem.as_bytes().as_ptr().add(last_elem.len());
        let first = input.first()?.as_bytes().as_ptr();
        let len = last.offset_from(first);
        Some(str::from_utf8_unchecked(from_raw_parts(first, len.try_into().unwrap())))
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the memory is already laid out correctly`?

Comment: Could you show the error you're getting?

Comment: @ShaneGervais There is no error, it's just unsafe code

Comment: `if you have a vector {"a", "bc"}, because vectors are contiguous,` true so far `the memory that it is pointing to looks like this: "abc"` Nope.

Comment: @finnW the memory is not laid out like you think. The Vec is an array of references, so something like this: `[(addr, size), (addr, size), (addr, size)]` The characters are stored elsewhere, likely not contiguously. Additionally, items of a Vec have to be the same size so it's not even possible to make a string type for which this works for strings of different length.

Comment: @finnw odds are good your code *looks* like it works correctly for the sole reason that you tested it on 'static strings, and the compiler laid them in order and contiguously [in the data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). And possibly something similar happened for sequentially allocated `String`. But it is entirely incorrect and unsound.

Comment: And even ignoring these it's trivially easy to show the function is incorrect: try it with `vec!["a", "b", "a"]`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get a combined `&str` from an arbitrary `Vec<&str>` without creating a separate allocation. You are correct that `Vec` stores its elements contiguously, but those elements are `&str` which are references. The *references* are stored contiguously, but that means nothing in regard to how the *referenced* data is organized. The memory structure of `input` would look akin to this:

```
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+
| ptr      |----->| [0].ptr  |----->| "a"      |
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+
| size     |      | [0].size |
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+
| capacity |      | [1].ptr  |----->| "bc"     |
+----------+      +----------+      +----------+
                  | [1].size |
                  +----------+
```

So you should simply create a new `String` using `.join("")`.